# Kaminari in Apotomo widget, links messed up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari, apotomo

I have Kaminari pagination inside an apotomo widget.
The pagination links render as expected until an apotomo event is fired. Then the pagination links render with a href that appears to be the url of the previous apotomo event:

```
transactions/render_event_response?...various parameters....
```

This is driving me nuts. Is there some confusion with a url_for_event method between apotomo and kaminari or something?

Rails 3.2.3
Apotomo 1.2.3
Kaminari 0.14.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with Kaminari, I've added a fix in my code that strips the unwanted data from the url that is added by Kaminari in views rendered from an apotomo event.

In application_helper.rb:

```
  def strip_apotomo_data_from_kaminari_url(url)
    url.gsub!('/render_event_response', '')
    if url =~ /\?/
      param_list = url.split('?')[1].split('&')
      param_list.reject!{ |p| p.start_with?('source', 'type') }

      url = url.split('?')[0] # strips all params
      url += '?'+ param_list.join('&')
    end
    url
  end
```

Then I called this helper to update the url from the 5 Kaminari pagination link partials: _page.html.erb, _first_page.html.erb and _last_page.html.erb, _prev_page.html.erb and _next_page.html.erb. (see the answer to [Unwanted form parameters being appended to pagination links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327917/unwanted-form-parameters-being-appended-to-pagination-links)).

Thanks to apotomo's Nick Sutterer for pointing me in the right direction https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cells-and-apotomo/vekawcXAHN0

The Kaminari bug is: https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/issues/131